# Automatically Double Space Text Area

Tags: php, html, nl2br

I have a text area that allows the user to input multiple lines of text. I would like to force everything in the text box to automatically be double spaced. I am using nl2br to output text and show the spacing.

**Lets say the user types:**

red
blue
green

**I would like the nl2br function to output**

red

blue

green

I would also need to be able to handle double spaces (i.e. if the user already puts in double spacing, I don't want more.

Any ideas on how to produce this? I would rather do it in the page that allows the user to enter the text if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [str_replace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) and [PHP_EOL](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

```
$str = 'red
blue
green';

$str = str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br><br>', $str);
echo $str;
```

**EDIT:**
Using regex:

```
$str = 'red

blue



green
blue';

$str = preg_replace(array('/(\r?\n)+/', '/\r?\n/'),array(PHP_EOL,'<br><br>'), $str);
echo $str;
```

Comment: thanks - need to update my question to ask if this will handle double spaces (i.e. if the user already puts in double spacing, I don't want more.)

Comment: you duplicated `\r?` I think you need it also for `\n?`

Comment: @Akam if you use `\r?\n?` this will match everything.

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: look at `array('/(\r?\n)+/', '/\r?\n/')` why `\r?` duplicated?

Comment: @Akam What i wanted to do is to make it work on both Linux and Windows. [To explain things out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline): Linux uses `\n` and Windows uses `\r\n`. The first `/(\r?\n)+/` will replace all new lines (double or triple lines, or more ...) with one new line `PHP_EOL` then we replace ALL `PHP_EOL` which you may match with `/\r?\n/` with double br's `<br><br>`. I hope i made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = nl2br(str_replace(PHP_EOL, '<br><br>', $str));
echo $str;
```

Comment: There's no reason to wrap it in `nl2br()` anymore. There are no newlines left after `str_replace()` has removed them.

Answer (score 0):

```
$str = str_replace('<br />', '<br /><br />', nl2br($str));
```

This will make `<br />` tags out of all line endings and afterwards double them.